# My PS4 controller is not turning on

Tags: controllers, ps4

My PS4 controller is not turning on. It only works when you plug it in the PS4 but not wirelessly. Please help me.

Comment: What happens when you disconnect the Controller from the PS4 while it's on? It sounds like a dead battery in the PS4 controller right now, but if that's the case, it should disconnect again once unplugged.

Comment: Have you used the controller with another device, e.g. a PC/Mac? I assume that it has previously worked with your PS4?

Comment: if it isn't a battery problem like Alex pointed, it could be a bluetooth problem with your PS4 no working as expected or simply broken.

Comment: If you dropped your controller recently you could have either damaged or disconnected something. Try opening it and checking the components. Plenty of videos of opening the controllers out there.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect your PS4 power cord then reset your controller using a pin or a paper clip . The reset bottom is at the left side of the controller (next to L2) once you have done that reset , connect power cord back then connect your controller to the PS4 (with USB cable ) then push PS4 botton (to turn on your PS4) . Then it'll work again .

Answer (score 1):

this is sure to work technique. just unplug the ps4 completely , remove all the cables, like power cable, hdmi cable, controller cable and keep it separately for an hour or more. remove the cables from both the ends like power sockets as well then after an hour connect it all back. it should work. i tried a lot like resetting , pressing share and psp button and much more, and nothing i mean nothing worked. and finally when i was going to take it to a private store for a check up, i just thought and connected it for one last time and walla it worked.
please try this method, it should work